# Google Apps Script JDBC - works only when remote database access hosts in cpanel is set to wide open

Tags: google-apps-script, cpanel

I am able to connect a google spreadsheet apps script to a mysql database, but only when my remote database access hosts in cpanel is set to the wide open %

if i put the ip addresses listed here into my access hosts list:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

i get the "failed to establish database connection" error.

i rewrote the access hosts to be far more broad than the actual google ranges - e.g. 66.102.%.%  but still no luck.

i went to try and figure out what ip address the script was running from to determine where the range might be broken. to get that value i attempted this:

```
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.whatsmyip.org/");
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

but that consistently runs with ip addresses outside the range given on the guide page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you've used the wildcard incorrectly? The % wildcard can match any character, not just numbers, so your example would actually be 66.102.%.